# Shopify NodeJS: Error creating Metafields: error 422 "type can't be blank"

Tags: node.js, rest, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to create metafields using the Shopify Admin REST API (with NodeJS).

This is a simplified version of the call I'm trying to make (see [documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/metafield#post-metafields)):

```js
const data = await client.post({
  path: 'metafields',
  data: { 
    "metafield": { 
      "namespace": "namespace123", 
      "key": "key123", 
      "value": 42, 
      "type": "number_integer"
    }
  },
  type: DataType.JSON,
});
```

But I get this error:

```
HttpResponseError: Received an error response (422 Unprocessable Entity) from Shopify:

{
  "type": [
    "can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

I've checked that the `type` attributes are set properly:
The root-level `type` is set correctly to `application/json`, and `data.metafield.type` is set following the rules [here](https://shopify.dev/apps/metafields/types).

I've also tried other types, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: I was using an old API version to initialize my Shopify Context:

```js
Shopify.Context.initialize({
  // ... other stuff ... //
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October20,
});
```

None of my other API calls relied on old breaking behaviour, so updating my API version fixed the issue without too much hassle:

```js
Shopify.Context.initialize({
  // ... other stuff ... //
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.January22,
});
```